# Modify length of Highcharts sankey-diagram connection line

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, sankey-diagram

I have got a question of Highcharts sankey-diagram.
Is there anyone can help me with changing the length of connection line?

[image: screenshot]

It's too wide between data columns. I want to narrow the size to half.

here is the sample code from hightchart demo:
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/sankey-diagram

Comment: Could you not just give the chart container half the width? The connections will try to fill the whole chart-space, which is logical.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `marginLeft` & `marginRight` properties to narrow the size of the series:

```
  chart: {
    marginLeft: 200,
    marginRight: 200
  },
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qygesf42/

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.marginLeft
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.marginRight